# Google Sheets - how can I return participants scores by team, sorted by score?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-query-language, textjoin

I have a sheet with participant scores, and each participant is in a team. In a second sheet, I have the following formula to create a subset of participant scores per team in each row.

Here's a link to a [sheet with sample data showing my formula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExnFdF65kqqD8IkRxKL3Vboo-H081Q-XwqvxXFFM8b8/edit?usp=sharing):

How can I get the results sorted in decreasing numerical order?

I've tried using the SORT() function (column C in the second sheet), but understandably, it interprets the results as text, so a score of 10 is ranked lowest.

Comment: Just by looking at your question (not seen the data) it sounds like `QUERY()`

Comment: Thanks JvdV - just had a look at the documentation on QUERY() - looks like I would  need to be familiar with SQL?

Comment: @nquirer https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this superior formula after you delete everything in range `A:B`:

```
={"Team", "Scores"; INDEX({UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(data!B2:B, data!B2:B<>""))), 
 FLATTEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(SORT(QUERY(
 QUERY({data!B2:B, TEXT(data!C2:C, "000000")&CHAR(13)&"("&data!A2:A&")"}, 
 "select min(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"),
 "offset 1", 0), SEQUENCE(COUNTA(data!A2:A)), 0), 
 "^0{1,5}", ),,9^9)), " ", CHAR(10)))})}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, @player -  you've given me hope that a more complex sort is possible - posted in this question: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68528248/google-sheets-how-can-i-return-votes-by-team-sorted-by-the-most-popular-votes) - I've tried adapting your query, but it's way beyond me!

Comment: @nquirer I had a look on your another question and not rly sure I understand what should be the desired output there (how many columns & where/why/based on what). perhaps you could give some pointers on what do you wish to do there?

Comment: thanks a ton @player - I've added two columns to the 'formula' tab of the sheet linked in the other question (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bF08VMh2d60j8_vcqVhukSvyqL8n2T4lAUYGA1_nA08/edit?usp=sharing) - column C shows you my existing formula, and column D shows the desired output - so what would be great is to extend your query above to add the third column (I've inserted your query in E1).

Answer (score 2):

Just replace 2nd parameter of `SORT` function with `Score`.

> =if($A:$A="","",arrayformula(textjoin(" ",true,sort(if(Team=A2,Score&" ("&Name&")",""),Score,false))))