# Google Sheets - how can I return votes by team, sorted by the most popular votes?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, textjoin

I have a sheet with participant votes, and each participant is in a team. In a second sheet, I have the following formula to create a subset of participant votes per team (followed by voter name) in each row.

> =if($A:$A="","",arrayformula(textjoin(" ",true,sort(if(Score=10,"",if(Team=A2,REGEXREPLACE(Improve&" -
> "&Detail&" ("&Name&")","/n"," "),"")),1,true))))

How can I get the results sorted in decreasing order of votes (show the most popular votes first, then the 2nd most popular, etc.?

In case there are two or more topics with the same number of votes, it would make sense to use voter names as secondary sort criteria.

Here's a link to a [sheet with sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bF08VMh2d60j8_vcqVhukSvyqL8n2T4lAUYGA1_nA08/edit?usp=sharing).

I've tried using the SORT() function (column C in the second sheet), sorting the results alphabetically, so at least the votes are effectively grouped, but I need to display the most popular issues first, as shown in column D.

The query formula in E1 was provided as answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520591/google-sheets-how-can-i-return-participants-scores-by-team-sorted-by-score) and I've tried manipulating the formula, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(
 {data!B2:B&"×", COUNTIF(data!B2:B&data!D2:D, data!B2:B&data!D2:D), data!D2:D&"♥("&data!A2:A&")"}, data!C2:C<10), 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1), 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(data!C2:C)-COUNTIFS(data!C2:C, 10))}, 
 "select max(Col3) where not Col1 starts with '×' group by Col4 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×")), " ", CHAR(10)), "♥", " "),,2)
```

[image]

or with previous:

```
={"Team", "Scores", "What needs improvement"; 
 INDEX({UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(data!B2:B, data!B2:B<>""))), 
 FLATTEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(SORT(QUERY(
 QUERY({data!B2:B, TEXT(data!C2:C, "000000")&CHAR(13)&"("&data!A2:A&")"}, 
 "select min(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"),
 "offset 1", 0), SEQUENCE(COUNTA(data!A2:A)), 0), 
 "^0{1,5}", ),,9^9)), " ", CHAR(10)))}), 
 INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(
 {data!B2:B&"×", COUNTIF(data!B2:B&data!D2:D, data!B2:B&data!D2:D), data!D2:D&"♥("&data!A2:A&")"}, data!C2:C<10), 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1), 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(data!C2:C)-COUNTIFS(data!C2:C, 10))}, 
 "select max(Col3) where not Col1 starts with '×' group by Col4 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×")), " ", CHAR(10)), "♥", " "),,2)}
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bRqNXV5Ox3Vs6O6J7B9RQkAXr3SB-X3fOtqYzlE69iA/edit#gid=106582906)

Comment: Thanks @player, this delivers the results in the demo sheet - though I'm not able to apply it to my actual data - which has a number of additional columns. I noticed your solution relies on a blank line at the bottom of the sheet - with my sheet, the data comes in from a form, so I can't rely on a blank line at the bottom.
That said, I've added the blank line to test and I still get the error: ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Comment: @nquirer fixed, answer and demo sheet updated, see if it works on real dataset

Comment: thanks! much appreciated - will check it out.

Comment: I've come across a case where all team members vote 10/10 so there are no  entries in the "Improve" column and this breaks the formula - how can I cater for this?

Comment: I've updated the demo spreadsheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bF08VMh2d60j8_vcqVhukSvyqL8n2T4lAUYGA1_nA08) to show this case

Comment: @nquirer fixed. see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bRqNXV5Ox3Vs6O6J7B9RQkAXr3SB-X3fOtqYzlE69iA/edit#gid=851849385 you can test it with A:D columns in that same sheet

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to show the scores for the Gamma team who all rated 10 - currently it's only showing ratings for the other teams. Also, I need to show the members of the other teams who rated 10 (currently excluded). I've shown this in a copy of your sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LhdIFkK6KqNd_bW87x0msprhQUfTusoQBxrQ-5WTchE/edit#gid=851849385

Comment: @nquirer sheet you shared in your last comment is private. for the gamma... what should 2nd and 3rd column show if all the game scores are 10? empty cells? coz initial formula would exclude all ppl if they would score 10

Comment: Sorry about that - have made the sheet public. 2nd columns shows scores with names, 3rd column shows empty cells (nothing to improve).

Comment: @nquirer fixed. see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a-pMWaQ33zWTj4lemo7SUFgE3i5NB_aNdAnwZzKN9SU/edit#gid=111509152

Comment: thanks player0, but I see that if the team has more than 1 rating of 10, the new formula returns a line break at the top of the results cell - is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @nquirer are you sure? I am not able to reproduce it in latest sheet I shared (on Sheet6)

Comment: yes, player0 - you can reproduce the issue by giving Becky or Ulla a score of 10, and deleting the relevant Improve entry (if they give a rating of 10, the form doesn't ask what needs to be improved).

Comment: @nquirer please see and edit to show the issue: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a-pMWaQ33zWTj4lemo7SUFgE3i5NB_aNdAnwZzKN9SU/edit#gid=0

Comment: oddly enough - if I (i) clear the Improve comment for the highlighted rows (Harry or Ulla), the formula works correctly with no leading line break, and if I (ii) go and change another score to 10 and clear that Improve comment, the formula works correctly with no leading line break, BUT if I (iii) go and change another score to 10 and clear that Improve comment, AND then clear one of the highlighted rows (Harry or Ulla), the formula creates a leading line break. Unfortunately I don't understand the formula well enough to understand what causes this.

Comment: @nquirer fixed https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a-pMWaQ33zWTj4lemo7SUFgE3i5NB_aNdAnwZzKN9SU/edit#gid=0 try it if its ok